# How to Increase the max size of char array using c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is my code. The problem is increasing the size of a char array. It only works until index = 4. It won't go to index = 5 or forward.

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var guesser = new BrutePasswordGuesser();

        var guess = new String(guesser.CurrentGuess);
        while (textBox1.Text != guess)
        {
            textBox2.Text = guess;
            if (!guesser.NextGuess())
            {
                Label2.Text = "Maximum guess size reached.";
                break;
            }
            guess = new String(guesser.CurrentGuess);
        }

        if (textBox1.Text == guess)
  {
            textBox2.Text = guess;
            Label1.Text = "Password Correct";
        }
    }
    private class BrutePasswordGuesser
    {
        private const int MaxAscii = 126;
 //i have to use 13 here
        private const int MaxSize = 4;

        private const int MinAscii = 33;

        private int _currentLength;

        public BrutePasswordGuesser()
        {
            //Init the length, and current guess array.
            _currentLength = 0;
            CurrentGuess = new char[MaxSize];
            CurrentGuess[0] = (char)MinAscii;
        }

        public char[] CurrentGuess { get; private set; }

        public bool NextGuess()
        {
            if (_currentLength >= MaxSize)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Increment the previous digit (Uses recursion!)
            IncrementDigit(_currentLength);

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increment the character at the index by one. If the character is at the maximum 
        /// ASCII value, set it back to the minimum, and increment the previous character.
        /// Use recursion to do this, so that the proggy will step all the way back as needed.
        /// If the very bottom of the string is reached, add another character to the guess.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="digitIndex"></param>
        private void IncrementDigit(int digitIndex)
        {
            //Don't fall out the bottom of the array.
            //If we're at the bottom of the array, add another character
            if (digitIndex < 0)
            {
                AddCharacter();
            }
            else
            {
                //If the current character is max ASCII, set to min ASCII, and increment the previous char.
```

When `digitIndex` reaches 4 the code starts iterating and doesn't go to 5 or farther.

```
                if (CurrentGuess[digitIndex] == (char)MaxAscii)
                {

                    CurrentGuess[digitIndex] = (char)MinAscii;
                    IncrementDigit(digitIndex - 1);
                }
                else
                {

                    CurrentGuess[digitIndex]++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddCharacter()
        {
            _currentLength++;
            //If we've reached our maximum guess size, leave now and don't come back.
            if (_currentLength >= MaxSize)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Initialis as min ASCII.
            CurrentGuess[_currentLength] = (char)(MinAscii);
        }
    }
```

It only works for maxsize 0-4 but I have to use it for 13 and 14. Can anybody solve that brute force code to increase size of char array.

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`, `c++`, `vb.net`?

Comment: programmer can convert the logic from any language for usability

Comment: I doubt you wrote this piece of code

Comment: nops i have taken but this is not answer

Comment: only need an example to increase the size of char array from 4 to 10\

Comment: `new char[4]` → `new char[10]`, be specific. Take a moment and learn how to create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve), this would help a lot and gives better answers.

Comment: the code runs and not stops when i increase the size more than 4

Comment: the above wold not work index does not exceed 4

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to increase size of array after allocating memory for the first time. In this code MaxSize is equal 4 so it works well from 0-4  when increase it gives error because size of array is limited. In your case the MaxSize means the maximum size that your sytem may use, if the maximum is 14 just change  one line as below:

```
private const int MaxSize = 14;
```

Comment: but why index not exceed 4 when it reaches 4 it starts iterating again and again at 4 my brut force fails and index not moves to 5

Comment: C# is 0-indexed. Valid index values for size 4 are 0-3.

Comment: after 4 the index have to add character and move to 5 but fails

Comment: to be more precise: **arrays** are zero-indexed, because the first entry is at memory address *array_offset* + **0** * *element_size*

Comment: i edited above where CurrentGuess[digitIndex]  reached 4 it stops adding charecter and going to 5

Comment: The access syntax in C# generally tends to be 0-indexed. Lists, Collections, etc. Seems like splitting hairs considering the OP does not really seem to know what arrays _are_ much less use them

Comment: did you change MaxSize?

Comment: yes i changed but index stops at 4 not moves to 5 or 13 is faraway list store all values but not compare each stored value with textbox1 value